# Unresolved function or method filter() in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I use WebStorm 2017.3.1

On this code

```js
router.get('/costs/:id', ((req, res) => {
        let costsId = Number(req.params.id);
        let cost = costs.filter(cost => cost.id === costsId);
        res.send(cost);
    })
);
```

I get weak warning on `costs.filter`:

> Unresolved function or method filter()

[image: WebStorm Settings #1]

[image: WebStorm Settings #2]
How can I fix this warning?

Comment: Is `costs` defined somewhere else since it is undefined in the route handler function?

Comment: `const costs = require('../data/costs');`

Comment: What is `costs`?

Comment: json

`[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "category": "food",
    "title": "Meat"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "category": "food",
    "title": "Juice"
  }
]`

Comment: @DenisVasilenko What is the `typeof(costs)`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate  object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known issue, please follow [WEB-23188](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23188) for updates